# Will this laptop support higher size and speed RAM?

Tags: laptop, memory

I bought Lenovo S145 15IIL laptop (model [81W800FLIN](https://psref.lenovo.com/Detail/IdeaPad/ideapad_S14515IIL?M=81W800FLIN)).
It comes with 8GB soldered RAM which seem to run at 2666 MHz.
The processor is [1031G1](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/196603/intel-core-i5-1035g1-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-60-ghz.html) which seem to support 64GB @ 3200 MHz.
Lenovo says max 12 GB is supported. But some people have upgraded above 12 GB too.
For example in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fkkS0uzBqE4) video it is shown to work with 20GB RAM.

**Q1.** Will adding 16GB RAM (total 24GB) work?

**Q2.** Possibly at higher data rate? Or I have to stick to data rate of 2666MHz or lower?

Also crucial [says](https://www.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/lenovo/ideapad-s145-15iil) this laptop support max 20GB RAM.
**Q3.** If thats true, so does it still make sense to add additional 16GB?

**Q4.** Also is it that for proper dual channel, I should match the memory size with the existing one? That is, is there any performance benefit in adding additional 8GB over adding 16GB RAM?

Comment: The Intel specification page will list the maximum amount of memory in a "standard" configuration. Typically the "standard" is two channels with two modules per channel meaning four modules *in total*. If it supports 64GB in that configuration then the maximum module size is therefore 16GB (64 divided by 4). If you only have one slot then you can only fit one module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If that's true, so does it still make sense to add an additional 16GB?

Only you can decide if you want to spend the money.  You will have to remove the 4 GB module and replace it with the 16 GB module.  This would mean you would have 20 GB installed.  **That is the maximum amount of memory supports since it does not support 32 GB modules.**

> Will adding 16GB RAM (total 24GB) work?

Based on the research you have provided, a 16 GB module should work with your machine. In my personal experience, I have not seen any modern machine, that doesn't support 16 GB DDR4 modules.  32 GB DDR4 module support is still rare but starting to be more common.  **Your machine does not support 32 GB DDR4 modules.**  Furthermore, the maximum amount you can install, is 20 GB (16 GB + 4 GB).  **There is absolutely no way to get 24 GB due to the soldered memory module.**

> Possibly at a higher data rate? Or I have to stick to a data rate of 2666MHz or lower?

The fastest memory frequency your system supports, is 2666 MHz, **due to the soldered DDR 4 GB 2666 MHz module.**

If you install a DDR4 module that is slower than 2666 MHz, then your system will downclock all memory modules that speed, this is due to the 2666 MHz already in your system that cannot be removed.

Outside of a benchmark, you will NOT see a difference between 2666 MHz and 3200 MHz, even if it was possible with the system you had you would be talking about single-digit improvements.  **Your processor by the way is a major performance bottleneck due to its 1.0 GHz base frequency.**

> Also is it that for proper dual-channel, I should match the memory size with the existing one? That is, is there any performance benefit in adding an additional 8GB over adding 16GB RAM?

No;  You are talking about single-digit performance increases when comparing Dual and Single memory channel mode.  **Unless you are running out of memory, you likely won't see any significant improvement in system performance, installing additional memory only works if your system is low on system resources**

Comment: 16 GB module + 4 GB module is 20 GB.  Only you can decide if you want to spend money to upgrade the memory.  Single/Dual channel performance is also something you will only see improvements during a benchmark.

Comment: @Maha - Your system has 4 GB soldered not 8 GB.  If you provided the incorrect specifications for your system you should edit your question.  If your system actually has 8 GB soldered DDR 4, that significantly, changes my answer.  **It would actually completely invalidate my answer.**  Replacing the 4 GB soldered memory is not a realistic endeavor.

Comment: @Maha the link to your laptop specifications in your question states you have 4GB soldered and 4GB as an SO-DIMM. You would likely need to remove the SO-DIMM to fit a 16GB module giving, as Ramhoud states, 20GB total. `4GB Soldered DDR4-2666 + 4GB SO-DIMM DDR4-2666` is what is stated.

Comment: @Maha - Lenovo indicated 4 GB soldered.  So I will stand by Lenovo.  **Even that particular page indicates 8 GB total, which means, 4 GB soldered.**